# How to find days when workers don't show up for work

Tags: sql

I have a calender table for everyday in 2021. Also i have an entry table for workers everyday entries. It includes id and date columns. Calender just have date column. How can i find the days when the workers did not come? I thought searching days for every id would work

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join the worker entries to all possible combinations of date & id.
Then the unmatched entries will be seen as NULL.

```
select cal.cal_date, wrkr.worker_id
from (select distinct workingday as cal_date from worker) cal
cross join (select distinct id as worker_id from worker) wrkr
left join worker as ent
  on ent.workingday = cal.cal_date
 and ent.id = wrkr.worker_id
where ent.id is null
group by cal.cal_date, wrkr.worker_id
```

**Extra:**

Demo with a calendar and holidays

> ```
> create table calendar (
>  cal_date date not null primary key
> );
>
> create table holiday (
>  worker_id int not null, 
>  date_of_holiday date not null, 
>  primary key (worker_id, date_of_holiday)
> );
>
> insert into holiday 
> (worker_id, date_of_holiday) values
> (1, '2021-10-15');
>
> create table worker (
>  id int not null, 
>  workingday date not null, 
>  primary key (id, workingday)
> );
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- filling the calendar with the current and next year
> --
> with recursive rcte_calendar as
> (
>   select date_trunc('year', cast(current_date as date)) as day
>   , date_trunc('year', cast(current_date as date)) 
>     + interval '2 year' 
>     - interval '1 day' as maxday
>   union all
>   select day + interval '1 day', maxday
>   from rcte_calendar
>   where day < maxday
> )
> insert into calendar (cal_date)
> select day
> from rcte_calendar cte
> where not exists (
>   select 1
>   from calendar cal
>   where cal.cal_date = cte.day
> );
>
> -- what range does the calendar have
> select
>   date_part('year', cal_date) as year
> , min(cal_date)
> , max(cal_date) 
> from calendar
> group by date_part('year', cal_date)
> order by year;
> ```
>
> ```
> 730 rows affected
>
> year | min        | max       
> :--- | :--------- | :---------
> 2021 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31
> 2022 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- putting test data in worker
> --
> insert into worker (id, workingday)
> select wrkr.worker_id, cal.cal_date 
> from calendar as cal
> cross join (values (1),(2),(3)) wrkr(worker_id)
> where cal.cal_date between cast('2021-10-10' as date) 
>                        and cast('2021-10-22' as date) 
>   and extract(dow from cal.cal_date) not in (0, 6) -- no weekends
>   and not exists (
>       select 1 
>       from holiday as hol
>       where hol.worker_id = wrkr.worker_id
>         and hol.date_of_holiday = cal.cal_date
>   )
>   and not exists (
>       select 1 
>       from worker as wrkr2
>       where wrkr2.id = wrkr.worker_id
>         and wrkr2.workingday = cal.cal_date
>   );
>
> --
> -- worker 2 wasn't working on some days, so remove those
> --
> delete from worker 
> where id = 2 
>   and workingday in ('2021-10-15','2021-10-18','2021-10-19');
> ```
>
> ```
> 29 rows affected
>
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- how does it look so far
> --
> select *
> , extract(dow from workingday) as dayofweek
> from worker
> ```
>
> ```
> id | workingday | dayofweek
> -: | :--------- | --------:
>  1 | 2021-10-11 |         1
>  2 | 2021-10-11 |         1
>  3 | 2021-10-11 |         1
>  1 | 2021-10-12 |         2
>  2 | 2021-10-12 |         2
>  3 | 2021-10-12 |         2
>  1 | 2021-10-13 |         3
>  2 | 2021-10-13 |         3
>  3 | 2021-10-13 |         3
>  1 | 2021-10-14 |         4
>  2 | 2021-10-14 |         4
>  3 | 2021-10-14 |         4
>  3 | 2021-10-15 |         5
>  1 | 2021-10-18 |         1
>  3 | 2021-10-18 |         1
>  1 | 2021-10-19 |         2
>  3 | 2021-10-19 |         2
>  1 | 2021-10-20 |         3
>  2 | 2021-10-20 |         3
>  3 | 2021-10-20 |         3
>  1 | 2021-10-21 |         4
>  2 | 2021-10-21 |         4
>  3 | 2021-10-21 |         4
>  1 | 2021-10-22 |         5
>  2 | 2021-10-22 |         5
>  3 | 2021-10-22 |         5
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- The missing days, based on days other workers filled in
> -- But without considering the holidays
> -- 
> select d.days, wrkr.worker_id
> from (select distinct workingday as days from worker) d
> cross join (select distinct id as worker_id from worker) wrkr
> left join worker as ent
>   on ent.workingday = d.days
>  and ent.id = wrkr.worker_id
> where ent.id is null
> group by d.days, wrkr.worker_id
> ```
>
> ```
> days       | worker_id
> :--------- | --------:
> 2021-10-15 |         1
> 2021-10-15 |         2
> 2021-10-18 |         2
> 2021-10-19 |         2
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- Missing days, based on period and holidays
> --
> select cal.cal_date, wrkr.id as worker_id
> , count(case when ent.id is null then 1 end) 
>   over (partition by wrkr.id order by cal.cal_date) as rolling_count
> from calendar as cal
> cross join (select distinct id from worker) wrkr
> left join worker as ent
>   on ent.workingday = cal.cal_date
>  and ent.id = wrkr.id
> where cal.cal_date between cast('2021-10-10' as date) 
>                        and cast('2021-10-22' as date)
>   and extract(dow from cal.cal_date) not in (0, 6) -- no weekends
>   and not exists ( -- workers may be on holiday
>       select 1 
>       from holiday as hol
>       where hol.worker_id = wrkr.id
>         and hol.date_of_holiday = cal.cal_date
>   )
>  and ent.id is null -- the unmatched
> group by cal.cal_date, wrkr.id, ent.id
> order by cal.cal_date, wrkr.id
> ```
>
> ```
> cal_date   | worker_id | rolling_count
> :--------- | --------: | ------------:
> 2021-10-15 |         2 |             1
> 2021-10-18 |         2 |             2
> 2021-10-19 |         2 |             3
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- Missing day ranges, based on period and holidays
> --
> with cte_missed_work as
> (
>     select 
>       cal.cal_date
>     , wrkr.id as worker_id
>     , lag(cal_date) over (partition by wrkr.id 
>                           order by cal.cal_date) as prev_date
>     from calendar as cal
>     cross join (select distinct id from worker) wrkr
>     left join worker as ent
>       on ent.workingday = cal.cal_date
>      and ent.id = wrkr.id
>     where cal.cal_date between cast('2021-10-10' as date) 
>                            and cast('2021-10-22' as date)
>       and extract(dow from cal.cal_date) not in (0, 6) -- no weekends
>       and not exists ( -- workers may be on holiday
>           select 1 
>           from holiday as hol
>           where hol.worker_id = wrkr.id
>             and hol.date_of_holiday = cal.cal_date
>       )
>       and ent.id is null -- the unmatched
>       group by cal.cal_date, wrkr.id
> ), 
> cte_missed_work2 as (
>   select *
>   , sum(case when date_part('day', cal_date::timestamp - prev_date::timestamp) = 1 then 0 else 1 end)
>     over (partition by worker_id order by cal_date) as Rnk
>   from cte_missed_work
> )
> select worker_id
> , min(cal_date) as firstDate
> , max(cal_date) as lastDate
> , date_part('day', max(cal_date)::timestamp - min(cal_date)::timestamp)+1 as missing_days
> from cte_missed_work2
> group by worker_id, Rnk
> order by min(cal_date), worker_id
> ```
>
> ```
> worker_id | firstdate  | lastdate   | missing_days
> --------: | :--------- | :--------- | :-----------
>         2 | 2021-10-15 | 2021-10-15 | 1           
>         2 | 2021-10-18 | 2021-10-19 | 2
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1b07fa6250100cdac3e856a7d30c80d3)*

Comment: i didnt understand entry_timestamp

Comment: you didn't provide sample data, nor a more detailed layout of the tables with it's datatypes. So I had to make assumptions. One assumption is that the entries have a field that has both date & time. Like a timestamp or datetime.

Comment: i have calender table(days), worker(id,workingday)

Comment: The point of this example is to show you the concept of match the possible combinations against the existing combinations, then filter the unmatched.

Comment: Thanks. And btw, I didn't use the calendar table because it also contains the weekends and holidays. By taking the unique days from workers it should only get days that workers worked.

Comment: i have a little question. if i want to use calender table because of i have also a table for holidays. what would i do? just for guiding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239539/discussion-between-mert-and-lukstorms).

Comment: mr. i have an extra question. this program completely solved my problem. but I want to print how many days when the worker did not come to work in a new column. If worker_id 2 has not come to work for 5 days,I want to print 5 in the extra column next to each different day he did not come. how can i make it

Comment: @mert It would be too complicated to explain.  To count ranges of dates is a Gaps-And-Islands type problem.  I've updated the solution. Basically, calculate a ranking per worker_id & date range, then group on that.

Comment: Side-note. The weekends split up the ranges. But I think that's fine. If not, then I suggest to raise another question about it. *(not sure how to pull that off myself)*

Comment: No can do. But I'm guessing you wanted something like a cummulative count. So i've included that rolling_count to the solution.

Comment: Yes Yes Yes, This is exactly what i want thank you so so much